# using $(this).each inside a plugin not working jquery

Tags: jquery

i have this simple plugin but the `$(this).each()` is not working, it only calls once instead of onve for each of the selector which is  `$("input.[class~='checking']")` so bascailly i want to call the each once for each input box with a class of "checking" and i am totally lost as to why it is not working

```
(function ($) {
    moSHclass = ''
    $.fn.isCheckedMO = function (moSHclass) {
        $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").hide();


        $(this).click(function () {
            var amChecked = 0

            $(this).each(function () {

                if (this.checked == true) {
                    alert('am:' + amChecked)
                    amChecked = amChecked + 1
                }
            });
            if (amChecked > 0) {

                $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").show();
            } else {
                $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").hide();
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: `return this.each(function(){ var $this = $(this); $this.click(function(){`

Comment: i am not sure what you are referring to here?

Comment: shudnt that be `$("input[class~='checking']")`? without the `.`?

Answer (score 1):

this was solved by the below, i was getting a lot of responses, which i appreciated a lot that wanted me to assign the $(this) to a variable then use that variable instead of $(this) in the each() run.  However what worked was doing that and then putting that Variable inside $(mySelector) the parantheses and not inplace of the entire section.

```
(function($) {
moSHclass=''

$.fn.isCheckedMO=function(moSHclass) {
 $("input.[class~='"+moSHclass+"']").hide(); 

  $("td.[class~='"+moHTML+"']").addClass('red')


 var mySelector=$(this)
  $(this).click(function(){ 

var amChecked=0

    $(mySelector).each(function(){

  if (this.checked==true) { 

   amChecked=amChecked+1}
  });
if (amChecked>0) 
 {

 $("input.[class~='"+moSHclass+"']").show();
  }else { 
 $("input.[class~='"+moSHclass+"']").hide(); 
  }
 });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am willing to bet that you are trying to access `each` on the wrong `this`.  Try:

```
(function ($) {
    moSHclass = ''
    $.fn.isCheckedMO = function (moSHclass) {
        var whatIThinkYouWantThisToBe = $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']");
        whatIThinkYouWantThisToBe.hide(); 
        whatIThinkYouWantThisToBe.click(function () {
            var amChecked = 0
            //Store $(this) in $that for use within each callback...
            var $that = $(this);
            $that.each(function () {
                if (this.checked == true) {
                    alert('am:' + amChecked)
                    amChecked = amChecked + 1
                }
            });
            if (amChecked > 0) {

                $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").show();
            } else {
                $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").hide();
            }
        });
    }
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: this works the same, it only gives one alert even if two or more are checked

Comment: See my edit, it looks like the first reference to `this` is not what you think it should be.  Is it the same thing you are trying to hide?

Comment: the click button works just fine, and i don't want the class used to hide or show i want to use the selector for the plugin as the selector for my each()

Answer (score 0):

why you don´t do

```
$("input.[class~='checking']").each(...
```

insted of

```
$(this).each(...
```

?

Aditionaly you can debug in console, see what is $(this) at that point with

```
console.log( $(this) );
```

You culd save $(this) this way to:

```
(function ($) {
moSHclass = ''
$.fn.isCheckedMO = function (moSHclass) {
    var $self = $(this);
    $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").hide();


    $(this).click(function () {
        var amChecked = 0

        $self.each(function () {

            if (this.checked == true) {
                alert('am:' + amChecked)
                amChecked = amChecked + 1
            }
        });
        if (amChecked > 0) {

            $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").show();
        } else {
            $("input.[class~='" + moSHclass + "']").hide();
        }
    });
}
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: because if i did that i might as well put it inside the <head> the whole point is to give the end user the option to use any class they want

Comment: Then take the class as an option and then use it, or just make shure you have the correct object selected and save it in a var, the do de .each(). Is common to see some thing like var $self = $(this) in thr first line.

Comment: i could do that but i would rather get this working, it makes no since i can not use the selector in an each()

Comment: Have you tested with console.log( $(this) ); ? Because because the meaning of $(this) change after the  $(this).click(function () {...

Comment: it doesn't give me much, there must be another method to pass the selector in this case $("input.[class~='checking']") to the plugin, it just shouldn't be this hard

Comment: Put var $self = $(this) in the right place isn't that hard. Like marteljn say, i am willing to bet that you are trying to access each on the wrong this and store it on a var is the way to solve that.

Comment: not sure what you mean but that doesn't work, and if  i alert($(this)) it comes back as object object, maybe there just is no command for that i have goggled it every which way and no luck

Comment: Dont use alert, use consloe.log(), and see the conole (f12 in chrome), there you can see the object and expand it.

Comment: it gives me this [15:35:29.413] ({0:{jQuery17206386194140496742:2}, 1:{jQuery17206386194140496742:3}, 2:{jQuery17206386194140496742:4}, selector:"input.[class~='checking']", context:({}), length:3})

Comment: so how can i get selector: is that a built in variable , i saw it was depreciated

Comment: Just see when $(this) mean waht you want and save it to a var like in the exaple.

Comment: which i have done, and it still only gives me one run, okay wait

Comment: OKAY you comment trigered it in my old brain, so if i have myVar=$(this) then i needed to do $(myVar).each() working fine now,

Comment: Just mayVar.each() without the $() because it is already a jQuery object. If it´s solved, pleas mark the answer. Thks...

Comment: no that was the problem, i was trying it without and it failed over and over, with the debug or log on i noticed it was just giving me the selector so the Var was just the selector not the $() portion so when i put the variable inside the $() it worked perfectly,